# Swift Using a UISlider in a UITableViewCell the right way?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, uitableview, uislider

I am struggling to properly use UISliders in a UITableViewCell.
Here is the Idea:

- The User can set different Jobs which he needs to fulfil tasks. The amount of different Jobs cannot be known in advance. Lets say for example User1 needs for his Band only Guitarists and Drummers, where someone else needs Guitarists, Drummers, Singers, Keyboarders and so on.

What I want him to provide is that depending on which Jobs he needs, he can set the amount of people he needs for a specific job.
I am using a UISlider in a TableViewCell to let him do this.

But here comes the trouble:

(1) The Label under the UISlider doesn't show the right amount while the User drags the Slider
(2) The prepareForReuse function doesn't work properly. I want the User to have the Slider back at 0 and the Label showing 0 when a reused Cell gets used.
(3) Finally the `jobAmountNeeded` Array doesn't have the right values stored (or no values at all) and therefore the saved Amounts in Firebase aren't right.

In my opinion all three Problems are connect to the same source.

Therefore I would be more than pleased, if someone could help me. :)

Thanks for your help everyone!

```
class ProjectTeamViewController: UIViewController {

    // MARK: - Properties
    
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var headerSeperator: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var saveButton: UIButton!
    
    
    var sortedSoloJobs = [String]()
    
    var jobIndex: Int?
    var jobAmount: [String] = []
    var selectedJob:String?
    var sentProjectCreated:String?
    var projectCreated:String?
    var jobAmountNeeded = [JobNeeded]()
    

       
    var slider: [SliderClass] = []
    
    let step:Float = 1
    
    var selectedIndexPath: IndexPath?
    
    var tempArray = [99: "Baum"]
    var tempArray2 = [99: 5]
    var currentValue:Float = 0
    var key = 0
    


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        setUpUI ()
        getJobs(for: User.current) { (memberJobs) in
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }

    }
    
    
    // MARK: - Functions
    
        func setUpUI () {
            Utilities.addShadowtoView(headerSeperator)
            Utilities.addShadowtoButton(saveButton)
            saveButton.layer.cornerRadius = 6
            saveButton.layer.borderWidth = 1
            saveButton.layer.borderColor = UIColor.darkGray.cgColor
            
        }

        func getJobs(for user: User, completion: @escaping ([MemberJobsStruct]) -> Void) {
            var jobs = [String]() // All Jobs
            var soloJobs = [String]() // Solo jobs from all jobs

            let ref = Database.database().reference().child("team").child(user.uid)

            ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in

                for case let child as DataSnapshot in snapshot.children {
                    guard let value = child.value as? [String: Any] else {
                        return completion ([]) }

                    let memberJob = value["memberJob"] as! String
                    jobs.append(memberJob)
                    soloJobs = Array(Set(jobs))
                    self.sortedSoloJobs = soloJobs.sorted()
                    
                    DispatchQueue.main.async { self.tableView.reloadData() }
            } })
        }
    func json(from object:Any) -> String? {
        guard let data = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: object, options: []) else {
            return nil
        }
        return String(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
    }
  
   @objc func sliderValueChange(sender: UISlider){
         
    sender.isContinuous = false
    currentValue = round(sender.value / step) * step
    var sliderValue = Int(currentValue)
            sender.value = currentValue   // get slider's value
            let row = sender.tag               // get slider's row in table
                key = row
    
    
   
    if let row = self.jobAmountNeeded.firstIndex(where: {$0.jobKey == key}) {
    jobAmountNeeded[row].jobAmount = sliderValue
        }
    }
    
    @IBAction func saveAction(_ sender: Any) {

        if projectCreated == nil || projectCreated == "no Value" {
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "Internal Error send a bug report: #150420", preferredStyle: .alert)
                alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil))
                alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .default, handler: nil))
                self.present(alert, animated: true)
        } else {
        for value in jobAmountNeeded {
            let jobName = value.jobName
            let jobAmount = value.jobAmount
            let jobKey = value.jobKey
            let currentUser = User.current
            let jobreqRef = Database.database().reference().child("posts").child(currentUser.uid).child(projectCreated ?? "no Value").child("ProjectJobAmount").child(value.jobName)
            let project = JobNeeded(jobName: jobName, jobAmount: jobAmount, jobKey: jobKey)
            let projectDict = project.dictValue
                   jobreqRef.setValue(projectDict)  { err, jobreqRef in
//                       print("done")
            }
        }
    
        }
    }
    
    @IBAction func cancelAction(_ sender: Any) {
          self.view.window?.rootViewController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        
    }
    
}

extension ProjectTeamViewController: UITableViewDataSource {

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        
        return sortedSoloJobs.count    }

    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
        let sortedSoloJob = sortedSoloJobs[indexPath.row]
        
        
        let key = indexPath.row

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ProjectCharacterTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! ProjectCharacterTableViewCell
  
        cell.jobNameLabel.text = sortedSoloJobs[indexPath.row]
               
               jobAmountNeeded.append(JobNeeded(jobName: sortedSoloJob, jobAmount: 0, jobKey: indexPath.section))
               
               if let row = self.jobAmountNeeded.firstIndex(where: {$0.jobName == sortedSoloJob}) {
                   jobAmountNeeded[row].jobName = sortedSoloJob
                   }
           
             
        tempArray.updateValue(sortedSoloJob, forKey: key)

        let currentValue = cell.slider.value
        cell.slider.isContinuous = false
        cell.slider.tag = key
        cell.slider.minimumValue = 0
        cell.slider.maximumValue = Float(sortedSoloJob.count)
        cell.slider.addTarget(self, action:  #selector(sliderValueChange), for: .valueChanged)
        cell.jobAmountLabel.text = "\(currentValue)"
        return cell
            
          
        
    }
 
}
// MARK: - UITableViewDelegate

extension ProjectTeamViewController: UITableViewDelegate {
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {

        return  163
       
    }

}
```

```
class SliderClass: NSObject {
    var title: String?
    var subtitle: String?
    var sliderMinimum: Float?
    var sliderMaximum: Float?

    init(title: String, subtitle: String, sliderMinimum: Float, sliderMaximum: Float) {
        self.title = title
        self.subtitle = subtitle
        self.sliderMinimum = sliderMinimum
        self.sliderMaximum = sliderMaximum

    }
}

class ProjectCharacterTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    
    @IBOutlet weak var jobAmountLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var slider: UISlider!
    @IBOutlet weak var jobNameLabel: UILabel!
    
    
    
    
       
       override func awakeFromNib() {
           super.awakeFromNib()
            
        
    }
    
    override public func prepareForReuse() {
      // Ensures the reused cosmos view is as good as new
        super.prepareForReuse()
        self.jobAmountLabel.text = "0"
        self.slider.value = 0
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

}
```

Comment: While you may be right - three things are somehow connected - this is something I'd usually vote to close because it doesn't seem like any of these are connected. But I'd like to help. First, I use sliders in table cells frequently - they work. (I'd like to suggest some clarity on your end because I'm not exactly sure why your choice of using a slider(s) is a good one.) Anyways, break things down. For instance, remove the entire table view from things and simply put your slider and label in a UIView. Do *that* work? If not, then reusing cells is *not* the issue.

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply :)
I highly appreciate that you didn’t close the topic and offer help :)
In a view it works  perfectly. 
Would you mind posting a “sample code” of yours where you use UISliders in a TableViewCell? 

To customize it on my needs I think I’m capable of... you would do me a huge favor!!

Comment: I see you have an answer that you accepted. I'd still be happy to post my code. I'm seeing at least two differences that *may* complicate things. (1) I don't use IB, just straight code. (2) I pass slider values via notifications, not callbacks. Either way, I'm glad you got the help you needed. :-)

Comment: Still thanks for your help! I am a storyboard kid since my app is for academic purpose and it has to be "quick and easy" (at least quicker and easier with straight code) Still thanks for your help and for not closing the topic! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start simpler...

First, let's add a "current value" property to your `SliderClass` (I'm calling it a `SoloJob` class, as it seems more logical):

```
class SoloJob: NSObject {
    var title: String = ""
    var subtitle: String = ""
    var sliderMinimum: Float = 0
    var sliderMaximum: Float = 100
    var currentValue: Float = 0
    
    init(title: String, subtitle: String, sliderMinimum: Float, sliderMaximum: Float, currentValue: Float) {
        self.title = title
        self.subtitle = subtitle
        self.sliderMinimum = sliderMinimum
        self.sliderMaximum = sliderMaximum
        self.currentValue = currentValue
    }
}
```

We'll use the `currentValue` property to keep track of the slider value.

So, create a cell with a "title" label, a slider, and a "job amount" (or current value) label. I have it laid out like this:

[image]

In your cell class, connect the slider to an `@IBAction` for when it changes - ***NOT*** in your controller class.

Also in your cell class, add a "callback" closure var:

```
// closure to tell controller the slider was changed
var callback: ((Float) -> ())?
```

then, in your `@IBAction` func:

```
@IBAction func sliderValueChange(_ sender: UISlider) -> Void {
    let v = sender.value
    // update the label
    jobAmountLabel.text = "Current Amount: \(Int(v))"
    // tell the controller the slider changed
    callback?(v)
}
```

Back in your controller class, in `cellForRowAt`, setup the "callback" closure:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ProjectCharacterTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! ProjectCharacterTableViewCell
    
    let thisJob: SoloJob = sortedSoloJobs[indexPath.row]
    
    // set values / labels in the cell
    
    // closure to get notified when the slider is changed
    cell.callback = { val in
        // update our data
        self.sortedSoloJobs[indexPath.row].currentValue = val
    }

    return cell

}
```

When the user drags the slider, `@IBAction func sliderValueChange()` *in the cell class itself* will be called, and that's where we update the label in the cell **and** tell the controller the value changed.

Here is a complete implementation:

```
import UIKit

class SoloJob: NSObject {
    var title: String = ""
    var subtitle: String = ""
    var sliderMinimum: Float = 0
    var sliderMaximum: Float = 100
    var currentValue: Float = 0
    
    init(title: String, subtitle: String, sliderMinimum: Float, sliderMaximum: Float, currentValue: Float) {
        self.title = title
        self.subtitle = subtitle
        self.sliderMinimum = sliderMinimum
        self.sliderMaximum = sliderMaximum
        self.currentValue = currentValue
    }
}

class ProjectCharacterTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var jobAmountLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var slider: UISlider!
    @IBOutlet weak var jobNameLabel: UILabel!
    
    // closure to tell controller the slider was changed
    var callback: ((Float) -> ())?
    
    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    func commonInit() -> Void {
        contentView.layer.cornerRadius = 12
        contentView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
        contentView.layer.borderWidth = 1
        contentView.layer.masksToBounds = true
        contentView.backgroundColor = .white
        backgroundColor = .clear
    }
    func configureCell(_ theJob: SoloJob) -> Void {
        jobNameLabel.text = theJob.title + " - min: \(Int(theJob.sliderMinimum)) / max: \(Int(theJob.sliderMaximum))"
        slider.minimumValue = theJob.sliderMinimum
        slider.maximumValue = theJob.sliderMaximum
        slider.value = theJob.currentValue
        jobAmountLabel.text = "Current Amount: \(Int(theJob.currentValue))"
    }
    
    // connect valueChanged action in Storyboard
    @IBAction func sliderValueChange(_ sender: UISlider) -> Void {
        let v = sender.value
        // update the label
        jobAmountLabel.text = "Current Amount: \(Int(v))"
        // tell the controller the slider changed
        callback?(v)
    }
}

class ProjectTeamViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    var sortedSoloJobs: [SoloJob] = []
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // create some example data
        for i in 1...20 {
            // random slider minimum between 0 and 2
            let minVal = Int.random(in: 0...2)
            // random slider maximum between 5 and 10
            let maxVal = Int.random(in: 5...10)
            // start with current value at minimum
            let curVal = minVal
            let job = SoloJob(title: "Job Name \(i)", subtitle: "", sliderMinimum: Float(minVal), sliderMaximum: Float(maxVal), currentValue: Float(curVal))
            sortedSoloJobs.append(job)
        }
        
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.delegate = self
        
    }
 
}

extension ProjectTeamViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
    
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return sortedSoloJobs.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ProjectCharacterTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! ProjectCharacterTableViewCell
        
        let thisJob: SoloJob = sortedSoloJobs[indexPath.row]
        
        cell.configureCell(thisJob)
        
        // closure to get notified when the slider is changed
        cell.callback = { val in
            // update our data
            self.sortedSoloJobs[indexPath.row].currentValue = val
        }

        return cell

    }
    
}

extension ProjectTeamViewController: UITableViewDelegate {
}
```

and the Storyboard source (with all the `@IBOutlet` and `@IBAction` connections):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<document type="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.CocoaTouch.Storyboard.XIB" version="3.0" toolsVersion="16096" targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch" propertyAccessControl="none" useAutolayout="YES" useTraitCollections="YES" useSafeAreas="YES" colorMatched="YES" initialViewController="OoM-UM-qa5">
    <device id="retina4_0" orientation="portrait" appearance="light"/>
    <dependencies>
        <plugIn identifier="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder.IBCocoaTouchPlugin" version="16087"/>
        <capability name="Safe area layout guides" minToolsVersion="9.0"/>
        <capability name="documents saved in the Xcode 8 format" minToolsVersion="8.0"/>
    </dependencies>
    <scenes>
        <!--Project Team View Controller-->
        <scene sceneID="LA9-sV-8lR">
            <objects>
                <viewController id="OoM-UM-qa5" customClass="ProjectTeamViewController" customModule="TableAdd" customModuleProvider="target" sceneMemberID="viewController">
                    <view key="view" contentMode="scaleToFill" id="GWK-to-6GG">
                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="320" height="568"/>
                        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
                        <subviews>
                            <button opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" contentHorizontalAlignment="center" contentVerticalAlignment="center" buttonType="roundedRect" lineBreakMode="middleTruncation" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="I5Z-lW-4b3">
                                <rect key="frame" x="20" y="20" width="280" height="30"/>
                                <color key="backgroundColor" red="0.92143100499999997" green="0.92145264149999995" blue="0.92144101860000005" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                                <state key="normal" title="SAVE BUTTON"/>
                            </button>
                            <view contentMode="scaleToFill" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="Rkw-MO-6Op" userLabel="Horizontal Line View">
                                <rect key="frame" x="20" y="58" width="280" height="1"/>
                                <color key="backgroundColor" red="0.92143100499999997" green="0.92145264149999995" blue="0.92144101860000005" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                                <constraints>
                                    <constraint firstAttribute="height" constant="1" id="BkU-lx-Zp8"/>
                                </constraints>
                            </view>
                            <tableView clipsSubviews="YES" contentMode="scaleToFill" alwaysBounceVertical="YES" dataMode="prototypes" style="plain" separatorStyle="default" rowHeight="-1" estimatedRowHeight="-1" sectionHeaderHeight="28" sectionFooterHeight="28" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="pgu-lS-tk6">
                                <rect key="frame" x="20" y="67" width="280" height="481"/>
                                <color key="backgroundColor" systemColor="systemBackgroundColor" cocoaTouchSystemColor="whiteColor"/>
                                <prototypes>
                                    <tableViewCell clipsSubviews="YES" contentMode="scaleToFill" preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins="YES" selectionStyle="default" indentationWidth="10" reuseIdentifier="ProjectCharacterTableViewCell" rowHeight="109" id="tnK-1p-f4N" customClass="ProjectCharacterTableViewCell" customModule="TableAdd" customModuleProvider="target">
                                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="28" width="280" height="109"/>
                                        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask"/>
                                        <tableViewCellContentView key="contentView" opaque="NO" clipsSubviews="YES" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="center" preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins="YES" insetsLayoutMarginsFromSafeArea="NO" tableViewCell="tnK-1p-f4N" id="gcG-sV-dlw">
                                            <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="280" height="109"/>
                                            <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask"/>
                                            <subviews>
                                                <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" text="Job Name Label" textAlignment="natural" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="l3R-9V-mjm">
                                                    <rect key="frame" x="78" y="11" width="124" height="21"/>
                                                    <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="17"/>
                                                    <nil key="textColor"/>
                                                    <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                                                </label>
                                                <slider opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" contentHorizontalAlignment="center" contentVerticalAlignment="center" value="0.5" minValue="0.0" maxValue="1" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="mj1-CV-iWZ">
                                                    <rect key="frame" x="13" y="36" width="254" height="31"/>
                                                    <connections>
                                                        <action selector="sliderValueChange:" destination="tnK-1p-f4N" eventType="valueChanged" id="RkI-oL-0eQ"/>
                                                    </connections>
                                                </slider>
                                                <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" text="Job Amount Label" textAlignment="natural" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="xMH-9r-GO9">
                                                    <rect key="frame" x="70.5" y="70" width="139" height="21"/>
                                                    <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="17"/>
                                                    <nil key="textColor"/>
                                                    <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                                                </label>
                                            </subviews>
                                            <constraints>
                                                <constraint firstItem="l3R-9V-mjm" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="gcG-sV-dlw" secondAttribute="topMargin" id="DPl-Kl-d1J"/>
                                                <constraint firstItem="mj1-CV-iWZ" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="gcG-sV-dlw" secondAttribute="leadingMargin" id="Sx7-a7-Yxy"/>
                                                <constraint firstItem="mj1-CV-iWZ" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="l3R-9V-mjm" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="4" id="Z05-fI-eal"/>
                                                <constraint firstItem="xMH-9r-GO9" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="mj1-CV-iWZ" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="4" id="a8n-XL-xxa"/>
                                                <constraint firstAttribute="bottomMargin" relation="greaterThanOrEqual" secondItem="xMH-9r-GO9" secondAttribute="bottom" id="cg5-O7-mnS"/>
                                                <constraint firstItem="l3R-9V-mjm" firstAttribute="centerX" secondItem="gcG-sV-dlw" secondAttribute="centerX" id="hGU-ad-se2"/>
                                                <constraint firstItem="xMH-9r-GO9" firstAttribute="centerX" secondItem="gcG-sV-dlw" secondAttribute="centerX" id="p4W-nU-hxy"/>
                                                <constraint firstAttribute="trailingMargin" secondItem="mj1-CV-iWZ" secondAttribute="trailing" id="umL-5D-BUa"/>
                                            </constraints>
                                        </tableViewCellContentView>
                                        <connections>
                                            <outlet property="jobAmountLabel" destination="xMH-9r-GO9" id="AIQ-ro-Q2C"/>
                                            <outlet property="jobNameLabel" destination="l3R-9V-mjm" id="cA7-Kq-aRd"/>
                                            <outlet property="slider" destination="mj1-CV-iWZ" id="YDo-wV-0rA"/>
                                        </connections>
                                    </tableViewCell>
                                </prototypes>
                            </tableView>
                        </subviews>
                        <color key="backgroundColor" systemColor="systemBackgroundColor" cocoaTouchSystemColor="whiteColor"/>
                        <constraints>
                            <constraint firstItem="I5Z-lW-4b3" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="iax-Rw-gHC" secondAttribute="leading" constant="20" id="8bZ-vh-e2L"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="pgu-lS-tk6" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="iax-Rw-gHC" secondAttribute="leading" constant="20" id="KK9-MN-7TR"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="I5Z-lW-4b3" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="iax-Rw-gHC" secondAttribute="top" constant="20" id="MBM-in-OG7"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="Rkw-MO-6Op" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="iax-Rw-gHC" secondAttribute="leading" constant="20" id="NM3-Ah-IIR"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="pgu-lS-tk6" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="Rkw-MO-6Op" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="8" id="abw-Kr-4qh"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="iax-Rw-gHC" firstAttribute="bottom" secondItem="pgu-lS-tk6" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="20" id="dBK-83-lBg"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="iax-Rw-gHC" firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="I5Z-lW-4b3" secondAttribute="trailing" constant="20" id="erM-u3-zLO"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="Rkw-MO-6Op" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="I5Z-lW-4b3" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="8" id="ry1-D5-U89"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="iax-Rw-gHC" firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="Rkw-MO-6Op" secondAttribute="trailing" constant="20" id="vhe-jw-Dnb"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="iax-Rw-gHC" firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="pgu-lS-tk6" secondAttribute="trailing" constant="20" id="zdu-4p-FAt"/>
                        </constraints>
                        <viewLayoutGuide key="safeArea" id="iax-Rw-gHC"/>
                    </view>
                    <connections>
                        <outlet property="tableView" destination="pgu-lS-tk6" id="08E-xc-PqA"/>
                    </connections>
                </viewController>
                <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="Ns0-iW-ioz" userLabel="First Responder" customClass="UIResponder" sceneMemberID="firstResponder"/>
            </objects>
            <point key="canvasLocation" x="-534.375" y="839.78873239436621"/>
        </scene>
    </scenes>
</document>
```

Result:

[image]

And because we're updating our data array whenever a slider is changed, we can scroll through the table and reused cells will be configured properly.

When all of that makes sense, carry the methods over to your project to match your layout and data structuring.

Comment: Hey @DonMag I’m absolutely speechless! Thank you for that incredible answer! It functions perfectly and would have given me a lot of headache without your answer! 
Hope it may help other ones as well! :)